# How JDBCPagingItemReader fetches data

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on a batch job where I am using step partitioning and JDBCPagingItemReader used for data fetching with page size 100, thread count 5. I ran the program in debug mode for 3000 records in DB and found each of the thread is firing the below query to get the data from database.

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT CASE_NUM, STTS_CD, UPDT_TS, OFC_CD, OFC_NUM, CHNL_CD, APRV_OFC_CD, APRV_OFC_NUM,TYP_CD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE_NUM) AS rownumber FROM T_CASE WHERE PROC_INDX ='P' ) AS data WHERE rownumber BETWEEN :fromRow AND :toRow ORDER BY rownumber ASC FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY

My question is

1) If commit interval is 1 (This is because of my business requirement), then once the 100 record are processed by any thread then that thread will fire another query to get the next chunk of 100 records or it will keep firing the query and caches the data?

2) There would be only 5 thread * 100 chunk = 500 active records in memory at any certain point of time?

3) I am using in memory job repository. Is there any guidelines or best practices to avoid any OutOfMemoryError in such cases?

Expert seeking your help here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) With a commit interval of 1, a single thread would select the 100 records, and then begin processing and/or writing them as defined in the step.  After the completion of the Step, another query should be fired off to select another 100 records.

2) That is correct

3) One could increase the amount of memory given to the JVM at runtime. I'm unsure if you plan of having this being a process that spins up and is killed upon completion, or if the process will be running continuously over a period of time.  In either case however, if this is for a production level system the use of an in memory JobRepository is highly discouraged.  One of the major benefits of Spring Batch is the ability for it to look at historical records in the JobRepository for restarting a Job, as well as the ability for the developer to use it as additional data in determining any issues that a Job may encounter.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Waskiewicz for prompt answer. As your answer covers all my questions I am accepting your answer. One more question, any idea what would be size of job repository if I process 3000 DB rows with 5 threads?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the job more so than what you're processing.  The JobRepository is going to store information on the number of runs of the job, the JobParameters passed in, and the status of the Job/enclosed steps.  The more your job runs without the Java process terminating, the more records that will be generated (and therefore the more memory that will be used)

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, got it.